Playwright returning random timeout errors while running on GitHub pipeline
When I run my Playwright tests locally, they all pass. However, when I push the changes to my branch, the GitHub pipeline jobs triggered by my Pull Request encounter issues, and I’m unsure what’s causing them.
Multiple problems are occurring, but they basically all result in timeouts (->  Test timeout of 120000ms exceeded.
). It’s usually one of the following:

The page takes too long to load after navigating to a specific URL, leading to a timeout.
Waiting for an element with a specific "data-testid" (like a checkbox, icon, or button) that either doesn't load in time or doesn’t disappear as expected after loading.

Let me know if you need more details or additional information!
